# Using captcha in varnish setup

Tags: caching, security, proxies, advertising, captcha

Captcha and any form of page caching don't get along. I understand why this is, but i'm wondering if there might be a certain setup to use captcha even in cached environments.

Post requests for example are not cached in most cases. So using a captcha on a separate page right after the form submission that you intend to spam-protect should be possible in this case. Your first submission will only be validated if your captcha submission is valid.
   A **2-step validation**, like [cqcounter lookup form](http://cqcounter.com/whois/).

I can't find any examples where this is used in a cached drupal setup. Can this be done in drupal with captcha, or is holding a form submission while a second form is not validated not possible?